# How to complete dictionary by missing values

Tags: python

I would like to complete my dictionary which curently looks like this:

```
dict={3023:2, 3024:3, 3025:2, 3027:1}
```

where keys are successive numbers increasing by 1 and values are numbers of occurrences of a given number. As you can see there is missing key for example (3026) because number of occurance is 0. What is the best way to complete dictionary by missing items ? I would like to get dictionary:

```
dict={3023:2, 3024:3, 3025:2,3026:0, 3027:1,3028:0}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get a default value from a missing key in a dictionary, or how to find the number 3026, given the numbers 3023, 3024, 3025, 3027?

Comment: The answer depends heavily on why you need this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the max and min numbers, you can use this:

```
>>> d = {3023:2, 3024:3, 3025:2, 3027:1}   # <-- initial dict
>>> a, b = 3023, 3028   # <-- min and max values
>>> d = {n: d.get(n, 0) for n in range(a, b + 1)}   # <-- new dict
>>> print(d)
{3023: 2, 3024: 3, 3025: 2, 3026: 0, 3027: 1, 3028: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate from `min` to `max` value of the keys in the dict and create a new dict

```
>>> dct = {3023:2, 3024:3, 3025:2, 3027:1}
>>> {k:dct.get(k, 0) for k in range(min(dct), max(dct)+1)}
{3023: 2, 3024: 3, 3025: 2, 3026: 0, 3027: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use get with default value like :

```
dict.get(key, 0)
```

Also do not call a variable like type dict